# My image is not showing when I put @service.images each do .. I am not sure why as I have added associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I have an Index page to display all of my images in my service model. At first I was displaying all of these images using CarrierWave image tag as this is the tool I was using for user uploads and it worked perfectly. Half way through my project I changed my user image upload to ActiveStorage so that users could upload multiple images at a time. Now when I try and pull through the images that have been uploaded with Active Storage they do not display on my index page. I am using the exact same code to display the Active Storage images on my 'Show page' (it works there)  I don't know what the issue is.I get this error : undefined method `images' for nil:NilClass

Index.html.erb file code does not work and i get error message

```
<!-- desktop-->
<div class="desktop-jobs"><h1 class="completed-desktop">Completed Jobs.</h1>
  <% if @service.images.attached? %>

    <div class="row justify-content-around p-3">
      <% @service.images.each do |image| %>
        <div class="card card-main" data-aos="fade-up">
          <div class="m-2"><%= image_tag(image,:size => "400x400")%></div>
          <p class="text-position"><%= link_to service.name, service_path(service) %></p>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

model.rb

```
class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :images
   scope :with_eager_loaded_images, -> { eager_load(images_attachments: :blob) }
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
  validates :category, presence: true

end
```

show.html.erb (where the images actually display) similar code to index.html.erb

```
<% if @service.images.attached? %>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <% @service.images.each_with_index do |image, index| %>
      <% if index == 0 %>
        <div class="carousel-item active d-block w-100">
          <%= image_tag(image,:size => "400x400")%>
        </div>
      <% else %>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <%= image_tag(image, :size => "400x400") %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <%end %>
  </div>
<%end %>
```

controller params

```
 def service_params
    params.require(:service).permit(:name, :description, :category, :picture_url, :video, :photo, :photo_cache, images: [])
  end
```

Comment: You're probably missing some `@services = Service.all` in your controllers index method

Comment: ok I will check now,  I have `` @services = Service.all`` in my controller, I wish it was that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@service` is just one object.

You try to show images on the list page. So you need to send `images` method to every item of collection.

It will be something like this:

In your controller:

```
def index
  @services = Service.all
end
```

And in your view:

```
<% @services.each do |service| %>
  <% if service.images.attached? %>
    <% service.images.each do |image| %>
      <% if image.persisted? %>
        <%= image_tag(image.variant(resize: '100x100')) %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```